# Nonintersecting lattice paths with given start and endpoints

Tags: combinatorics, pathfinding

A prominent topic in combinatorics is the enumeration of nonintersecting lattice paths subject to certain conditions.  My goal is fairly simple: given starting points $(1,1), (2,1), \ldots, (k,1)$ and endpoints $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_k, y_k)$, I would like to generate all families of $k$ nonintersecting lattice paths with these start/endpoints.  By "lattice path," I mean a path in the plane whose steps are either $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.

My current method is hugely inefficient, because I first look at all $k$-tuples of paths with the prescribed start/endpoints, and then delete the ones in which the paths intersect.  In order to find all paths between $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$, I use `FindPath` and `GridGraph` as follows:

```
AllPaths[{{a_, b_}, {x_, y_}}] := 
  Map[{a - 1, b - 1} + # &, 
   Round[FindPath[GridGraph[{y - b + 1, x - a + 1}], 
      1, (x - a + 1) (y - b + 1), {x - a + y - b}, All] /. 
     Thread[Range[(x - a + 1) (y - b + 1)] -> 
       GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{y - b + 1, x - a + 1}]]]], {2}];
```

By repeating this for each start/endpoint pair, and then taking `Tuples` with one path from each set, I get the set of all families of lattice paths --- which is humongous, so that deleting the intersecting families takes a long time.

Is there a more efficient way to construct families of nonintersecting lattice paths?  Perhaps, for instance, by using `Fold` in some clever manner to restrict subsequent paths to the region bounded by their predecessor?